# How to determine that Switch changed its output?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a data source with the following header:

```
IObservable<IObservable<object>> MagicSource(IObservable<string> strings)
```

I push there the strings and its give me the results, but taking into accout, that I need answers only for the last string, I use Switch statement in order to cancel previous ones:

```
MagicSource(StringsProvider).Switch().Subscribe(r => {/*...*/});
```

That works well, but I also need to get a notification, that currently being processed string has changed for the purpose of preparing my results view. How to do obtain such notification?

Comment: Which of the things listed there is the enumerable your observable is subscribing to?

Comment: MagicSource is an external part of the strings query that selects its objects depending on given string and returns those objects as observable.

Comment: If it's a new observable can you call switch on it to get the most recent? or will everything it be the most recent?

Comment: I connect to MagicSource only once. Then it returns IObservable<object> for each pushed string. Switch makes that when new string is pushed, then previous IObservable<object> is being disconnected and only new IObservable<object> for new string is being subscribed.

Comment: I guess I don't know enough about IObservables to be of help, sorry =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally would avoid Do statements.

You could potentially create a projection.

In this projection I assume that you want to do your action on disposal of the current inner sequence (maybe clearing out the current records from a table?)

```
MagicSource(StringsProvider)
    .Select(inner=>inner.Finally(CleanUp))
    .Switch()
    .Subscribe(r => {/*...*/});
```

If you wanted to do the same but target the Subscription (not the disposal) of the inner sequence then you have a bit more work to do. I would create the symetrical operator to Finally, `Initially(Action)`

```
public static class ObservableEx
{
    public static IObservable<T> Initially<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Action onSubscribe)
    {
        return Observable.Create<T>(o=>{
            try
            {           
                onSubscribe();
                return source.Subscribe(o);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                o.OnError(ex);
                return Disposable.Empty;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And then you could use it like this

```
MagicSource(StringsProvider)
    .Select(inner=>inner.Initially(Prepare))
    .Switch()
    .Subscribe(r => {/*...*/});
```

Comment: I've just read your book _Introduction to Rx_. Your answer is also great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to just use a `Do` statement:

Here are some varieties.

If you know nothing about how `MagicSource` works and cannot exactly relate new incoming strings to new inner streams:

```
Action NewStreamProduced = ...;
MagicSource(StringsProvider).Do(_ => NewStreamProduced).Switch()....
```

If you do know that `MagicSource` will synchronously produce a new inner stream everytime a new string arrives, then you can put your `Do` before calling `MagicSource`:

```
Action<string> NewStringArrivedWhichMeansWeAreSwitching = ...;
MagicSource(StringsProvider.Do(NewStringArrivedWhichMeansWeAreSwitching)).Switch()...
```

Comment: ``Do`` has issues. Better to use multicast to generate another observable for the notification part. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18310461/158285

Answer (score 1):

You should add an index to each element indicating the sub source it came from. Pretty simple to do.

```
IObservable<Tuple<string, int>> results =
 MagicSource(StringsProvider)
 .Select((v,i)=>v.Select(y=>Tuple.Create(y,i))
 .Switch()
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the best way is the following. You need to use multicast.

```
// Ensure that you are using multicast
var source = MagicSource(strings).Publish().RefCount();

// Subscribe to this for notification and count
var notifications = source.Select((v,i)=>i);

// Subscribe to this to get flattened data
var flattened = source.Switch()
```

Doing `Publish().RefCount()` creates a multicast source that subscribes once when the first subscription is made and then unsubscribes when the last subscription is removed. The important thing to remember is that only a single subscription to the source is ever made which may or may not be important.